# EF Core 7: Ensure that foreign key is equal in two entities in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

I'm writing a small Application for stock-keeping. Within this Application, I've defined a StockLocation

```
public partial class StockLocation : ObservableObject
{
    public int StockLocationId
    {
        get;set;
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string locationName;

}
```

The StockItems are defined separately for each location. I'Ve done this, because we use unique numbers (unique for the location) for parts, but those unique numbers might describe a different item in a different location.

```
public partial class StockItem : ObservableObject
{
    public int StockItemId
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    [StringLength(100)]
    private string ident;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private StockLocation location;

    
}
```

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<StockItem>().HasIndex( "LocationStockLocationId","Ident" ).IsUnique(true);
    }
```

I now want to implement the functionality to take inventory. An inventory is assigned to a location, and then the items from that location with the present amount are assigned to the inventory. So something like this:

```
public partial class StockInventory : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private int id;

        [ObservableProperty]
        [Required]
        private StockLocation stockLocation;

        [ObservableProperty]
        [StringLength(50)]
        private string? costCenterNumber;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private DateOnly inventoryDate;

        [ObservableProperty]
        [StringLength(500)]
        private string? description;

        public ObservableCollection<StockInventoryItem> Items
        {
            get;
        } = new();


    }
```

```
public partial class StockInventoryItem : ObservableObject
{
    public int Id
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public StockInventory Inventory
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public StockItem Item
    {
        get;set;
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private double amount;

}
```

Now I'm wondering if it's possible to define a constraint, that the Foreign-Key property pointing to the Stock-Location has to be the same in the Inventory-entity and the underlying StockItem of the StockInventoryItem-entities. Is that possible?

I'll have to make sure that constraint is satisfied in the ViewModel, but I was wondering if it is possible to add that constraint to the model as extra security.

the underlying database is a SQL-database, in case that is relevant.

thank you very much!

Comment: That logic belongs to the dataservice the viewmodel uses to read/write the data. And that is one reason why you should not expose the entities to any layer except the dataservice.